# Unordered thread-safe collection to use as a pool?

Tags: c#, collections, pool

I created a pool class that when asked, finds or initializes an item and return it to the caller. I use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` as the underlying collection but I'm not sure whether it's the right type to use.

I don't need the items to be in any specific order, all I need is a thread-safe collection I can push to and pop from. Does .NET have a fast collection class for this purpose?

**Edit:** I used `ConcurrentBag<T>` after spender's answer:

```
public sealed class Pool<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> initializer;

    private readonly ConcurrentBag<T> bag;

    public Pool(Func<T> initializer)
    {
        if (initializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initializer");

        this.initializer = initializer;
        this.bag = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
    }

    public Pool(Func<T> initializer, IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (initializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initializer");

        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initializer");

        this.initializer = initializer;
        this.bag = new ConcurrentBag<T>(collection);
    }

    public Pool(Func<T> initializer, int allocationCount)
        : this(initializer)
    {
        if (allocationCount < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("allocationCount");

        for (int i = 0; i < allocationCount; i++)
            this.bag.Add(initializer.Invoke());
    }

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        this.bag.Add(item);
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        T item;
        return this.bag.TryTake(out item)
            ? item
            : this.initializer.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) sounds like just the ticket. You'll need to deal with the empty case yourself, but it seems to fit your needs quite nicely. In particular, [ConcurrentBag.TryTake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381774.aspx) will grab **an** item from the collection with no guarantee that any particular one will be returned.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Maybe include an example of its usage? Link only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779

`ConcurrentBag<T>` is the unordered equavalent of `ConcurrentQueue<T>`

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentBag` is an unordered collection and it is thread safe.